# How to delete records from MongoDB where a part of column value matches with given value

Tags: mongodb

I have TimeStamp column in a Collection in MongoDB. How to delete records whose Date in TimeStamp value matches with given date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.orders.deleteMany( { "date" : {$gt : <> , $lt : <>} //either one date or range});
```